# fancyhdr - Header Line is removed on beginning of chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

When compiling the code below, there is no line in the header in the beginning of the chapter.

How do I change it such that the header looks the same on all pages? Thanks

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancyplain} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{Titel} %Kopfzeile links
\fancyhead[C]{} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
\fancyhead[R]{Name} %Kopfzeile rechts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %obere Trennlinie

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lektion}
\chapter{velo}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\chapter{tram}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You want to redefine the `plain` page style by `\fancypagestyle`. Section 7 of the »[fancyhdr](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr)« manual has a detailed example.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig, `fancyplain` is used to change headers in all pages, _including_ `plain` ones.

Comment: @karlkoeller: This seems not to be documented in the manual.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Unfortunately not... I know about that from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customizing_with_fancyhdr (you can find something in this site as well searching for `fancyplain`.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Since I mostly use a class from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)«, I of course use »scrpage2« for page styles. For standard classes I'd prefer »[titleps](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps)« due to its better user interface. So this feature of »[fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)« is not so important to me. But nevertheless good to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fancyplain` style defines a new style for all pages, including `plain` ones.

So commands like `\fancyhead` take effect in all pages, but `\headrulewidth` not.

To change the behavior of the rule in `plain` pages you have to modify `\plainheadrulewidth`.

So, you have to add also

```
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancyplain} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[L]{Titel} %Kopfzeile links
\fancyhead[C]{} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
\fancyhead[R]{Name} %Kopfzeile rechts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %obere Trennlinie
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Lektion}
\chapter{velo}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\chapter{tram}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Output (first page):

[image]